# How to add HMAC Signature Authentication to your APIs in Kong API Gateway?

Tags: kong

I am trying HMAC authentication using **date** header as in https://getkong.org/plugins/hmac-authentication/

But still I am getting the error as

```
{
  "message": "HMAC signature cannot be verified, a valid date or x-date header is required for HMAC Authentication"
}
```

Please suggest a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the date header should not be used. Anyway I just replaced it with **x-date** header and the issue is solved.

Just make the request with an authorization header.

```
Authorization : hmac username="<username>",algorithm="hmac-sha1",headers="X-Date",signature="Ee4Gv1at78U3f+bawoV0PucdF/Q="

X-Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 10:28:40 GMT
```

In order to generate the string that is signed with a key, the client MUST take the values of each HTTP header specified by headers in the order they appear. That's why X-Date header is specified here.

Signature is the `Base64(HMAC-SHA1(signing string))`

The client would compose the signing string here as:

```
X-Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 10:28:40 GMT
```

You can also make use of one or more headers to create the signature. However this is the simplest one.

Visit : https://getkong.org/plugins/hmac-authentication/